# Bayesian AB Testing and Normal Distribution: How to Implement Posterior Variance Samples

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, normal-distribution, ab-test

I'm running an bayesian AB test to compare a normally distributed metric with unknown mean and variance between two groups. My goal is to compare the average value of the metric between the two groups, similar to a t-test. A toy example is shown below:

```
library(bayesAB)

# Creating metrics from two groups
set.seed(1234)
group_a <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5, sd = 1)
group_b <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 7, sd = 2)

normal_test <- bayesTest(
  A_data = group_a, B_data = group_b,
  priors = c("mu" = 1, "lambda" = 1, "alpha" = .001, "beta" = .001),
  distribution = "normal")

posterior_mu <- bind_rows(normal_test$posteriors$Mu)
posterior_sigma_sq <- bind_rows(normal_test$posteriors$Sig_Sq)
```

After running the test, we have posterior samples for the mean and the variance for the two groups. It seems straightforward to take the posterior mean samples and calculate various metrics like win rate, credible intervals for the mean difference, expected loss, etc.

My question would be, how should I go about taking into account the posterior variance samples when comparing the posterior mean samples? Should I just compare the posterior variance samples separately, or should I implement them in my comparison of the posterior mean samples somehow?